# How should I index content of my Android application

Tags: android, xamarin, google-search, google-search-api, android-app-indexing

I'm trying to implement Google App Indexing in one of my application. Content in my applications is divided into chapters:

- Linear motion
- Projectile motion

Each chapter is presented as one view, but there are a few sections in each of those views, for example Linear motion contains:

- Displacement
- Average velocity

I was able to index my data only by chapter title, but I'd like also to index all section titles. I tried to index all sections for the same app uri, but it looks like than only last entry is used.

Sample in C# (I'm using Xamarin):

```
foreach (var item in data)
        {
            var viewAction = Action.NewAction(Action.TypeView, item, baseAppUri);
            AppIndex.AppIndexApi.Start(client, viewAction);
        }
```

Is it possible to index few items to point to the same uri, or maybe I should stick with indexing chapter title only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a question asked in Webmaster Central Help Forum, where it explains you can have multiple Web URLs with the same App URI.

[Here is the link to the question](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/NK0u292x3BY;context-place=topicsearchin/webmasters/Is$20$27android-app$27$20necessary$20for$20app$20indexing$20or$20a$20custom$20uri$20is$20enough$3F)

You can also find more info at https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/android/publish where you need to report an activity in the API, but it should only do once per app URI visit.

Cheers

Comment: This is what I was looking for: Thing object = new Thing.Builder()        .setName(mIitle).setDescription(mDescription).setUrl(mUrl).build(); Thanks!